# IRC server doesn't respond to Rust IRC Client identify requests

Tags: tcp, rust, irc

I'm working on an IRC bot using TcpStream from the standard library.

I'm able to read all the lines that come in, but the IRC server doesn't seem to respond to my identify requests. I thought I was sending the request too soon so I tried sleeping before sending the IDENT but that doesn't work. I write using both `BufReader`, `BufWriter` and calling `read` and `write` directly on the stream to no avail.

```
use std::net::TcpStream;
use std::io::{BufReader, BufWriter, BufRead, Write, Read};
use std::{thread, time};
struct Rusty {
    name: String,
    stream: TcpStream,
    reader: BufReader<TcpStream>,
    writer: BufWriter<TcpStream>,
}
impl Rusty {
    fn new(name: &str, address: &str) -> Rusty {
        let stream = TcpStream::connect(address).expect("Couldn't connect to server");
        let reader = BufReader::new(stream.try_clone().unwrap());
        let writer = BufWriter::new(stream.try_clone().unwrap());
        Rusty {
            name: String::from(name),
            reader: reader,
            writer: writer,
            stream: stream,
        }
    }
    fn write_line(&mut self, string: String) {
        let line = format!("{}\r\n", string);
        &self.writer.write(line.as_bytes());
    }
    fn identify(&mut self) {
        let nick = &self.name.clone();
        self.write_line(format!("USER {} {} {} : {}", nick, nick, nick, nick));
        self.write_line(format!("NICK {}", nick));
    }
    fn read_lines(&mut self) {
        let mut line = String::new();
        loop {
            self.reader.read_line(&mut line);
            println!("{}", line);
        }
    }
}
fn main() {
    let mut bot = Rusty::new("rustyrusty", "irc.rizon.net:6667");
    thread::sleep_ms(5000);
    bot.identify();
    bot.read_lines();
}
```

Comment: Have you considered fixing the warnings that the compiler *already tells you about*? If not, perhaps you would share why you've chosen to ignore the warnings.

Comment: The warnings I'm getting all are dead code errors. I didn't think it was relevant enough to mention.

Comment: No, they aren't. If you would take the time to remove the warnings, you'd note that you are calling a method *that can fail* but you are ignoring the potential failure.

Comment: Which source for the IRC protocol are you using? The quick searches I've done don't agree with the format of data you are sending, so it'd be good to see what you are trying to do in addition to what you are actually doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very important to read the documentation for the components we use when programming. For example, the docs for [`BufWriter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufWriter.html) states (emphasis mine):

> Wraps a writer and buffers its output.
>
> It can be excessively inefficient to work directly with something that
>   implements `Write`. For example, every call to write on `TcpStream`
>   results in a system call. A `BufWriter` keeps an in-memory buffer of
>   data and writes it to an underlying writer in **large, infrequent
>   batches**.
>
> The buffer will be written out when the writer is dropped.

Said another way, the *entire purpose* of a buffered reader or writer is that `read` or `write` requests **don't** have a one-to-one mapping to the underlying stream.

That means when you call `write`, you are only writing *to the buffer*. You also need to call [`flush`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html#tymethod.flush) if you need to ensure that the bytes are written to the underlying stream.

---

Additionally, you should:

1. Handle the errors that can arise from `read`, `write`, and `flush`.
2. Re-familiarize yourself with what each function does. For example, `read` and `write` don't guarantee that they read or write as much data as you ask them to. They may perform a partial read or write, and it's up to you to handle that. That's why there are helper methods like `read_to_end` or `write_all`.
3. Clear your `String` that you are reading into. Otherwise the output just repeats every time the loop cycles.
4. Use `write!` instead of building up a string that is immediately thrown away.

```
fn write_line(&mut self, string: &str) {
    write!(self.writer, "{}\r\n", string).unwrap();
    self.writer.flush().unwrap();
}
```

With these changes, I was able to get a `PING` message from the server.